# add new data to native storage

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic native storage, and saving few objects in it, I need to add new data to the existing storage

```
carCleanForm(form){
        console.log(form.value);
        this.nativeStorage.setItem("carClean", form.value);
    }
```

so here every time when I invoke the form a new set of data will be added on clicking "carclean" button.

Could someone help me to add new data and as well as I need the old data, so on accessing the storage I should have the old object and new object listed

Comment: You need store both old and new data?

Comment: ya exactly if 1 is entered and stored and 2 is entered and stored i should be able to view 1 and 2 and two different objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store it in two object `prevCarClean` and `carClean`

```
carCleanForm(form){
  this.nativeStorage.getItem('carClean') .then(
    data => {
      let dataArray = data;
      dataArray.push(form.value); 
      this.nativeStorage.setItem("carClean", dataArray);
    },
    error => console.error(error)
  );
}
```

Comment: daily or weakly i need 1 month data i might clean daily at that time how would i store data

Comment: Sorry, i did not get you. What problem with daily or weekly?

Comment: like can we add more data

Comment: You want to store more than 2 value?

Comment: ya say i need to store around 30 data, will this able to hold